# Issue with Regular Expression Validator for text box in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, c, validation

Im having issues with the RegularExpressionValidator in my code!

I have 2 text boxes in my html page and in the code i have the sql command that inserts the parameters to the DB, the issue is that if i put a special character to the text box the sql stops because i need the validators, so i tried validating like this.

```
Insert the files number.
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" MaxLength="10" ></asp:TextBox>
```

```
Whats the users Name <br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
```

The validator is defined as:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" ValidationExpression="^\d+$" 
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

But when loading it ignores my validation expresion.

Please what is missing.

Thanks

Comment: <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
    runat="server" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" ValidationExpression="^\d+$" ControlToValidate="TextBbox1"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

Comment: Thats my validator for the first text box

Comment: There is a typing mistake in the value of `ControlToValidate`. Is that the problem?

Comment: No its not Connors, i made a mistake while retyping it. any other clue?

Comment: I added an answer. Can you put the markup of the validator in the question? It would be better than showing it as a comment.

Comment: I just tried that but its not working.. Its ignoring the validator and goes directly to the SQL ExecuteNonQuery where it shoows the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked everything and finally got it,

I had to add to my `web.config` the following:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And that solved my issues

Comment: It would be useful to accept this answer. I sometimes refer to this post but people don't know which answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see a mark next to the field when validation fails, you should set the `Text` property of the validator:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Text="*" />
```

Also, if you want to see the error message, you must have a `ValidationSummary` in your form.

Comment: I just tried that but its not working.. Its ignoring the validator and goes directly to the SQL ExecuteNonQuery where it shoows the error

Comment: Just curious: what value do you type? When I test it on my side, it works.

Comment: Another question: do you disable the validator in code-behind?

Comment: im adding a "+" or "." value, special characters that shouldnt be inserted to the textbox

Comment: I havent modified anything in code behind, i only have the sql connection inside the buttons object.

Comment: I have no clue then. You may try to put that markup in an empty project (it should work) and try to find what is different from your real project.