# ASP.Net RequiredFieldValidator not working

Tags: asp.net

I got problem with  RequiredFieldValidator , it is not working well ! The data is sent even if there is empty filed !! I tried many ways and non of them is working.
here is the code , I wish you resolve my problem.

```
 <form id="form4" runat="server">
                   <fieldset style="width: 295px; height: 68px;">
        <legend><h2>Contact Us Form</h2></legend>
    </fieldset> <p>
        <table style="height: 218px; width: 563px">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    Name
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server" Width="180px" ValidationGroup="cbSiteValidate"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style5">

                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredName" runat="server"  ControlToValidate="txtname" ErrorMessage="Name is Required" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="cbSiteValidate"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    Conatct Number
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtcontact" runat="server" Width="180px" ValidationGroup="cbSiteValidate"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                 <td class="auto-style5">

                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredNumber" runat="server"  ValidationGroup="cbSiteValidate" ControlToValidate="txtcontact" ErrorMessage="Number is Required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    Email
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtemail" runat="server" TextMode="Email" Width="180px" ValidationGroup="cbSiteValidate"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                 <td class="auto-style5">

                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredEmail" runat="server"  ValidationGroup="cbSiteValidate" ControlToValidate="txtemail" ErrorMessage="Email is Required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                     <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtemail" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Email is not correct" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    Message
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtmessage" runat="server"  ValidationGroup="cbSiteValidate" style="margin-bottom: 0px" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="120px" Width="220px" OnTextChanged="txtmessage_TextChanged1"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                 <td class="auto-style5">

                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredMessage"   ValidationGroup="cbSiteValidate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtmessage" ErrorMessage="Message is Required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" class="auto-style4">

                    <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnsubmit_Click" ValidationGroup="cbSiteValidate"  />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr><td colspan="3">

                <asp:Label ID="Lblmsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td></tr>

        </table></p>
             </form>
```

Comment: I tested your table markup and the validation worked well when clicking on `btnsubmit`. Is there a particular case that doesn't work? Or anything special going on in client code or in code-behind (e.g. disabling a validator)?

Comment: Maybe Hans Ajani's answer to his question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36465684/issue-with-regular-expression-validator-for-text-box-in-asp-net/36465743#36465743

Comment: the message is sent to my email successfully , it should be not !!  this is the problem

Comment: Now it is working with Hans solution , thanks a lot