# Validators not preventing postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, gridview

I have a GridView inside a content page. In the GridView I can do Delete and Insert. For insert, I need make sure the input of StudentNo and Amount cannot be empty. So I used RequiredFieldValidator. The problem is when I click the insert, it still postback even those two textboxes are empty. In my server side function, GridView_RowCommand I always have to put a check of if(Page.IsValid). My question is why RFV won't stop at the client side even validation failed.  Following is my aspx code, can anyone help me to see what I missing?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentMain" Runat="Server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        ShowFooter="true" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="40" AllowSorting="True" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' CommandName="DeleteRow" runat="server" 
                CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this row?')" 
                Font-Underline="True" Font-Bold="True">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label_ID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbInsert" CommandName="InsertRow" ValidationGroup="Insert" runat="server" 
                Font-Underline="True" Font-Bold="True" CausesValidation="true">Insert</asp:LinkButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="InstCode" SortExpression="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label_InstCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("InstCode") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="StudentNo" SortExpression="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label_StudentNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StudentNo") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtStudentNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvStudentNo" runat="server" ErrorMessage="StudentNo is a required field" 
                    ControlToValidate="txtStudentNo" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Insert">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AccountType" SortExpression="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label_AccountType" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AccountType") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount" SortExpression="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label_Amount" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Amount") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAmount" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Amount is a required field" 
                    ControlToValidate="txtAmount" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Insert">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" ValidationGroup="Insert" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" />
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Maybe the solution to this post will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36465684/issue-with-regular-expression-validator-for-text-box-in-asp-net/36465743#36465743

Comment: @ConnorsFan: whats the solution to that post? How are this and the other related at all?

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's Hans Ajani's answer to his own post. He should accept it because it is referred to quite often these days. I will leave him a comment to that effect. Addendum: the validators are ignored in Hans' post also (the postback occurs while it shouldn't), so it seemed to me that it is a situation similar to GLP's one.

Comment: Just tried. Still posting back.

Answer (score 0):

I'm moving my comment here because there is more to think about

Validation within a GridView, especially when you bypass GridView's editing modes, causes a postback due to event bubbling.

Server Control Click events bubble up the the Gridview and trigger a postback that can be intercepted in the GridView RowCommand event. You need to intercept the click and make a call to `event.stopPropagation()` or `set event.cancelBubble = true` depending on your browser:

```
void some_js_onclick_function_called_within_a_gridview( event ) {
  if ( event.stopPropagation )
    event.stopPropagation();
  else
    event.cancelBubble = true;
}
```

But then you have to contend with the validation, which is easy enough as ASP.NET has a client API for validation: [ASP.NET Validation in Depth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside)

The simplest answer is to remove the input fields from the GridView footer, sacrifice the "look and feel" to handle the validation without the Gridview mucking things up.

Or, leave the button in the footer but convert the LinkButton server control to a basic html `<button>` control and set the `onclick` attribute to some validation function as above and make a call to `__doPostBack('SomeEventTargetName', 'SomeEventTargetArgument')` on successful clientside validation.  Always check the inputs on the server side as well as a security measure.

For a more complete idea of the ASP Client Validation API look in the obj directory of your published project for `WebUIValidation.js`.

```
i.e.: obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Scripts\WebForms\WebUIValidation.js
```